# How to increase the decimal length for edge info

Tags: mesh

When I enable my mesh display, and click on the edge info. The only information I get back is a whole number, and a decimal point to the nearest tenths place. This is because the length is past the 100 mark, if it was 99, it would have the decimal increase to the hundredths place.

[image]

[image]

This is a brand new file, no extra information is added except the default cube.

There has to be somewhere to increase the length of the decimal places to be shown through edge info.

Answer (score 0):

A temporary fix to this, is to make the whole number, and then add the smaller length at the end, then once you are done. You can just dissolve the middle edges. [image]